# Error C2662: Cannot convert from const to a reference

Tags: c++, class, oop, visual-studio-2010, syntax-error

I am a first year student and have just started learning C++. My program throws up the C2662 error (my compiler is Express 2010+). Could you please help me out. My program snippet is given below:

```
class Book
{
private:
    string title;
    string author;
    string type;
    int date;
    int numberOfPages;
public:
    Book();
    Book(const Book& book);
    ~Book();
    void setBookTitle(const string& title);
    void setAuthorName(const string& author);
    void setBookType(const string& type);
    void setDateofPublication(const int& date);
    void setNumberofPages(const int& numberOfPages);
    void print(const Book& book);
    string getBookTitle()const;
    string getAuthorName()const;
    string getBookType()const;
    int getDateofPublication()const;
    int getNumberofPages()const;
    Book changeBookTitle(const Book& book);
    Book changeAuthorName(const Book& book);
    Book changePublicationYear(const Book& book);
    Book changePublicationType(const Book& book);
    Book changeNumberofPages(const Book& book);
    Book operator=(const Book& book);
    bool operator==(const Book& book);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& in, Book& book);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Book& book);
};
void Book::setBookTitle(const string& title)
{
    this->title=title;
}
    Book Book::changeBookTitle(const Book& book)
{
    string title;
    cout<<"The current title of the book is "<<book.getBookTitle()<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter the new title: ";
    cin>>title;
    book.setBookTitle(title);
    cout<<"The new book title is: "<<book.getBookTitle()<<endl;
    return book;
}
```

I tried using a const_cast<&string>title (I read it up on Stack), but the error persisted.
The error message I am getting is: error C2662: 'Book::setBookTitle' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const Book' to 'Book &'
With the help of @user3365922, I have removed the const modifier from the function definition and I am not getting any more errors. However, will it affect my passing by reference?

Comment: Can you add your error message also?

Comment: `setBookTitle` isn't marked const, but you pass const reference to `Book::changeBookTitle` and call `book.setBookTitle(title);`.